# How to set a specific language for a controller method returning a Thymeleaf template?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, localization, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring Boot application with Thymeleaf.
I have setup localization using LocaleChangeInterceptor and LocaleResolver and it's working fine.

What I want to understand is how can I set up a controller method to return a template always in a specific language?

For example, suppose the application supports different languages like fr, es, en, etc and I want to use 'en' as a default language only for my User Dashboard Controller and not for the entire user session, i.e. **language change should not reflect the entire user session.**

Please suggest.

Comment: Just don't provide translations for those keys and it will fallback to the default language.

Comment: @M.Deinum The same template is used in other controller methods, where localization support is required. So I have to define keys in message.property

Comment: If it is the same template then why not just use multi language? Also a bit strange to use the same page from different controllers imho.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it's a fragment that is re-used in multiple pages, and on some pages, only English support is required.